# When I add a new custom Customer attribute I get Fatal Error on click save or submit button

Tags: customer-attribute, fatal-error, eav-attributes, magento2.3.2

I manage to add my custom customer attribute with InstallData on my custom module it appears everything is working fine, but when i try save or edit customer  in front end or admin panel, when i click on the Save Button when editing a customer or creating a customer i got this error. 
I'm on Magento V 2.3.2

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text::validateLength() must be of the
>   type string, null given
>   vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php on line 141.

Here is the InstallData I used to create the attribute.

```
<?php

namespace Kmdelectronics\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'cedula_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Cedula',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => true,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cedula_attribute');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
                [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
                ]);
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that your attribute doesn't created properly Please share code which you have used to create customer attribute.

Comment: Hi, @Vivek thanks for your answer, i just added the code I used to create my attribute, also i editted the position directly from the db to change it to 39 because i want to display it before the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was because I didn't add the values attribute_set_id and attribute_group_id to my attribute if someone else have the same problem is here the UpgradeData method I create to solve my problem.

Also, can be the same problem if your attribute is required: false, your form will be ok but the attribute never will go to the db.

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', "<")) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $setup->startSetup();
            $attributesInfo = [
                'cedula' => [
                    'label' => 'Cedula',
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'position' => 38,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true
                ]
            ];
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
                $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
            }
            $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cedula');
            $Attribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'],
            ]);
            $Attribute->save();


        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```